# How to test with Expect Call on a function that is called within a loop using gmock?

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a bit of code that sends an HTTPRequest and depending on what the response is, will retry the request a number of times after a short wait.

I have no idea how to mock this out, this is what I have so far

```
  EXPECT_CALL(*requester, send_request(HttpResponse))
      .Times(1)
      .WillOnce(Return(0));
  HttpResponse response;
  response.status(HTTPSTATUS_NOT_FOUND);
  EXPECT_CALL(*mock_requester, response()).WillOnce(Return(&response)).WillOnce(Return(&response)).WillOnce(Return(&response)).WillOnce(Return(&response));

  EXPECT_THROW(loop_function("hello", true), std::runtime_error);
```

The actual function is very simple. It attempts to send an HttpRequest, then if it gets back a non 200 response, it will retry up to 3 times. I want to test to make sure it should fail 4 times before throwing an error but gmock is not cooperating (I know the function works, just want to figure out this gmock test)

Comment: I worry that this question isn't specific enough. Are you asking how to use the "MOCK_METHOD"?

Comment: Im wondering how to use the EXPECT_CALL for a function that is called within a loop and when that function is called, its returns a different value each time it is called. I know how to use google mock for a function that is just called a single time and then returns a value, but cant figure out how to handle the expect_call when the function call its expected is called multiple times within a loop (4 times to be exact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `WillOnce` calls on an expectation, like in this minimal example:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using testing::Return;

class MyMock {
public:
        MOCK_METHOD0(get_status, int());
};

int main(void)
{
        MyMock m;
        EXPECT_CALL(m, get_status())
                .WillOnce(Return(404))
                .WillOnce(Return(404))
                .WillOnce(Return(404))
                .WillOnce(Return(200));
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                std::cout << m.get_status() << std::endl;
}
```